# How to get all numbers out of a string and add them?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, string, xml

I have to parse a .xml file generated to summarize the results of a running a testSuite on some software. In a line I have, for example:

```
<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />
```

This indicates the number of tests failed, not executed, and passed. I need to figure out how many tests were in the test Suite, so I'd need to add, in the case above, 10+0+18065 = 18075.

How can I do this in Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply throw away all characters that are not digits and not space:

```
echo '<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />'|\
sed -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g'
```

gives

```
10 0 0 18065
```

.

The sum can be done with dc (with the timeout field filtered as requested)

```
echo '<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />'|\
sed -e 's/timeout="[0-9]*" //' \
    -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g' \
    -e 's/^ *//' \
    -e 's/ *$//' \
    -e 's/ /+/g' \
    -e 's/^/0 /' \
    -e 's/$/pq/'|dc
```

.

#### Description

As a sed script this would look like this

```
s/timeout="[0-9]*" //    #remove the timeout
s/[^0-9 ]//g             #drop anything but numbers and spaces
s/^ *//                  #drop spaces at the beginning of the line
s/ *$//                  #drop spaces at the end of the line
s/ /+/g                  #replace remaining spaces with +
s/^/0 /                  #add a 0 to initialize the sum for dc
s/$/pq/                  #add print and quit command for dc
```

The script can be simply used with

```
INPUT|sed -f script.sed
```

. I leave it for you to apply this script with sed and dc for multiline input. The one I wrote just works on one line!

Comment: The 3rd number is "timeout" and should not be added. Would I simply use `sed -d ' ' ` to select the first, second, and fourth partition? Or is there a better way?

Comment: you can simply add a `-e 's/timeout="[0-9]*" //'` as the first expression to sed.

Comment: I don't think you need to drop `(^ *| *$)` - they shouldn't matter to `dc`. It's a compiler, it expects tokenized input and doesn't care about spacea of any kind. I think. That said - there have been a *lot* of `dc`s, and I've only ever got familiar w/ one. Anyway, if you wrote the `sed` like: `sed '/[0-9]/!d;s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*/ \1/g` you'd know most out in one go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html) for proper xml parsing.

For your issue:

```
total=0; \
for i in failed notExecuted pass; do \
    sum=`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//Summary/@$i" test.xml`; \
    total=$(($sum + $total)); \
done; \
echo "Total=$total"
```

where `test.xml` is your file containing the xml data.

Comment: @farid99 - Just copy your data into a file like test.xml, copy paste the above commands on the bash prompt & you are good to go

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl`

```
perl -lne 'my @a=$_=~/(\d+)/g;$sum+=$_ for @a; print $sum' file
```

Using `awk`

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file | 
    awk '/[0-9]+/ {gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $0); sum+=$0} END {print sum}'
```

---

*Example*

```
% perl -lne 'my @a=$_=~/(\d+)/g;$sum+=$_ for @a; print $sum' foo
18075

% tr ' ' '\n' < foo | 
    awk '/[0-9]+/ {gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $0); sum+=$0} END {print sum}' 
18075

% cat foo
<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one with `dc`:

```
{   tr -cs 0-9 \\n 
    echo '[pq]sq[z2>q+l+x]s+l+x'
}   <<\IN | dc
<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />
IN
```

`dc` first reads in the whole infile - after `tr` has squeezed every sequence of not-number chars into a single `\n`ewline - and afterward it reads in a little `echo`ed loop macro string which tells it to add all values on its stack each to the next until fewer than two remain, at which point it just prints whatever the sum was and quits. In this case the sum is...

---

```
18075
```

If you have a GNU `dc` you might write it like:

```
tr -cs 0-9 \\n <in | dc -f- -e'[pq]sq[z2>q+l+x]s+l+x'
```

Or, if the infile is very big, you'll want to block it, too, to keep `dc` from buffering too much on its stack at once.

```
(tr -cs 0-9 \\n|xargs -n128|tr \  +)<in |
 dc -e'[pq]sq' -e'0[?z2>q+l+x]s+l+x'
```

...which will buffer 128 numbers at a time.

Like this:

```
seq -skfkridmdk 100000 |
(tr -cs 0-9 \\n|xargs -n128|tr \  +)|
 dc -e'[pq]sq' -e'0[?z2>q+l+x]s+l+x'
```

---

```
5000050000
```

If you're sure of the four per line thing, *and* you want to drop `*timeout=*` then you could do:

```
<in  grep '^<Summary'   |
     cut -d\" -f2,4,8   |
     tr \" \\n          |
     xargs -n512        |
     tr \  +            |
     dc -e'[?z2>q+l+x]s+'\
        -e\[pq]sq -e0l+x
```

Which will only tally *failed,notExecuted,pass* so long as their `"` relative positions are constant and those are the only kinds of input lines which might match `^<Summary`. I tried it like:

```
for x in 512 4096 16384; do time \
yes $'kdkeifndjei\n<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />'|
     grep '^<Summary'   |
     cut  -d\" -f2,4,8  |
     head -n1000000     |
     tr \" \\n          |
     xargs -n"$x"       |
     tr \  +            |
     dc -e'[?z2>q+l+x]s+'\
        -e\[pq]sq -e0l+x
done
```

...for 3 tallies of 3mil values a piece, and the results were:

```
18075000000
4.00s user 0.04s system 72% cpu 5.549 total
18075000000
2.82s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 2.831 total
18075000000
2.67s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 2.680 total
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an XML parser such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) with the file given in the question:

```
$ xml sel -t -m '//Summary' -v '@failed+@notExecuted+@timeout+@pass' -nl file.xml
18075
```

If the `Summary` node is found is several places, there will be one line of output for each node.

On some systems, XMLStarlet is installed as `xmlstarlet` rather than as `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the one of @ikrabbe. Think that this should work: `echo '<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />'| sed -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g' | cut -d" " -f2,3,5 | tr " " "+" | bc`
The fields start with 2 since there is a space at the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Building on ikrabbe's answer.

```
echo $(($(echo '<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />' | sed -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g' -e 's/ /+/g' -e 's/[+]*$//')))
```

gives "18075"

Explanation of code:

- Echo the text, then pipe it into sed for parsing using 3 sed
  statements.
- 1st sed-statement - Remove all but numbers and spaces ("
  10 0 0 18065 ")
- 2nd sed-statement - Exchange spaces with addition
  signs ("+10+0+0+18065+")
- 3rd sed-statement - Remove trailing
  plus-signs ("+10+0+0+18065"). The inbuilt bash-calculator gets angry
  if you give it a calculation that end with an operator)

Everything is then wrapped in this bash-function:

```
$(( ))
```

Which computes what is inside it, and thus gives you the answer in a single line of code.

This is a two line version. Just fil the string "input" with the lines you want to process.

```
input="<Summary failed="10" notExecuted="0" timeout="0" pass="18065" />"
echo $(($(echo $input | sed -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g' -e 's/ /+/g' -e 's/[+]*$//')))
```